# How to hide/remove title bar on Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

How can I remove title bar on flutter bar?

```
displayMap() {
    mapView.show(new MapOptions(
        mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:
        new CameraPosition(new Location(11.052992, 106.681612), 3.0),
        showUserLocation: false,
        title: 'Google Map'));

         .....
  }
```

I tried add `Container(height: 0.0)` and remove `title: 'Google Map'` but it only remove 'Google Map' text.

[image]

Edited:

My `Scaffold`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Demo App'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Touch'),
            color: Colors.blue,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 7.0,
            onPressed: displayMap,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in your `Scaffold` you need to remove your `appBar` property:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
        //delete your appBar property in your related Scaffold.
        body: YourBodyWidget(),
    );
```

**Edit :** it is related with the `map_view` plugin

```
  MapOptions(
      {this.showUserLocation: false,
      this.showMyLocationButton: false,
      this.showCompassButton: false,
      this.hideToolbar = false,
      this.initialCameraPosition: _defaultCamera,
      this.title: "",
      this.mapViewType: MapViewType.normal});
```

these are the default `MapOptions` may be you can try to set `hideToolbar:true` but it is not what you want I think,

I think they are not provide a parameter to close `appBar`,

Lastly I would recommend to use [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin, this plugin only render the **map** and developed by **Flutter Team** so you can easily configure other staff in your page/scaffold.

Comment: In my `Scaffold` I had remove `AppBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Demo App'),
      ),` and remove `title` on `displayMap()` but it not ok

Answer (score 20):

In some cases it is necessary to work with the AppBar but without displaying the title and one of these cases is when we have AppBar and TabBar together.

**In this case you will need to remove the AppBar title and include the following property: toolbarHeight: 0**

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: TabBar(
        isScrollable: false,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: (index) { },
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: "Pending"),
          Tab(text: "Done"),
        ],
      ),
      //this property
      toolbarHeight: 0,
    ), body: TabBarView(...)
  )
)
```