# hide android title bar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Welcome ,
I have a problem in my android **flutter ** app
I have this title bar ( label bar )
how can I hide it ?

[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cFjg.png)

My AndroidMainfest

```
 <application
        android:label="App Title"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70764837/421195

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old version: res > values > styles.xml or New version: res > values > themes.xml

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="MyTheme">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Also you can try in Android manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".activity.ContinueLoginActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I have never encountered such a situation before. I thought it was probably caused by kotlin. I hope it helps. Enjoy your work.

Comment: this problem suddenly happened when I changed SDK version to 33 , your solution solved the problem , thank you so much